# Why does $\dim\mathbb{F}=1$ imply that the only subspaces of $\mathbb{F}$ are $\mathbb{F}$ itself and $\{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading through an argument which states the implication in the question above. Intuitively this statement makes sense to me but I couldn't figure out why exactly it holds. I understand why $\mathbb{F}$ and $\{0\}$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{F}$ but not why they are the only subspaces of $\mathbb{F}$. (Here $\mathbb{F}$ denotes either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.)

Thanks for considering my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$, with $\dim V=1$. Then, $\dim U\leq1$. Therefore, $\dim U=0$ or $\dim U=1$.

Suppose $\dim U=0$. This means that $U$ has a basis with $0$ vectors. Thus, $U=\text{span}(\varnothing)$. By definition, $\text{span}(\varnothing)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$. Therefore, $$U=\{\mathbf{0}\}.$$

Suppose $\dim U=1$. We will prove that $U=V$.

Since $U$ is a subspace of $V$, we have $U\subseteq V$. Now, let $\mathbf{u}\neq0$ be a basis of $U$. Since this list is linearly independent and has length equal to the dimension of $V$ ($\dim V=1$), then it must
be also a basis of $V$. It follows that any vector $\mathbf{v}\in V$ can be written as $$\mathbf{v}=a\mathbf{u}$$, where $a\in\mathbb{F}$. Since $a\mathbf{u}\in U$, this implies that $\mathbf{v}\in U$ for all $\mathbf{v}\in V$. Therefore, we have $V\subseteq U$. Therefore, $U=V$.

Therefore, $\dim V=1$ implies that the only subspaces of $V$ are $\{\mathbf{0}\}$ and $V$ itself.

Answer (score 4):

A subspace $W$ of $F$ which is not the zero subspace contains a non-zero field “vector” $x$. Any other field “vector” $y$ is simply a scalar multiple $y= (y/x) x$, and the division is justified because viewed as an element of the field, $x$ is non-zero so has a multiplicative inverse. So, $y$ also belongs to the subspace $W$ (by closure under scalar multiplication), but this proves the whole field $F$ is contained in the subspace $W$. But by definition, $W$ is contained in $F$, so this completes the proof of equality $W=F$.

Comment: Try to generalize for yourself why the only subspaces of a 1-dimensional vector space are the zero subspace and the entire vector space. Hint: you will need to explicitly use the defining property of being 1-dimensional (in my answer above, since you’re dealing with the field itself, I gave a more ‘direct’ answer).

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is any finite dimensional vector space over a field $k$, then for each $n\in\{0,1,\cdots,\dim V\}$ there is at least one subspace $U_n$ of $V$ with $\dim U_n=n$ and conversely any $U\le V$ must have $\dim U\in\{0,1,\cdots,\dim V\}$. As special cases, there is one and only one subspace with dimension zero and with dimension $\dim V$.

In particular, $\Bbb F=\operatorname{span}_{\Bbb F}(\{1\})$ is $1$-dimensional over itself. Subspaces must have dimension between $0$ and $1$ so must be zero or one dimensional. By very general facts, that forces all subspaces to be either the zero space or $\Bbb F$ itself.